# Range scans on columns using Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

My column family stores data in the column names and I want to perform range query on the columns using Astyanax. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots example on range query available [here](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-thrift/src/test/java/com/netflix/astyanax/thrift/ThriftKeyspaceImplTest.java)

Sample one

```
keyspace.prepareQuery(CF_TIME_UUID)
    .getKey(rowKey)
    .withColumnRange(
        new RangeBuilder()
            .setLimit(10)
            .setStart(TimeUUIDUtils.getTimeUUID(0))
            .setEnd(TimeUUIDUtils
                .getTimeUUID(Long.MAX_VALUE >> 8))
            .build()).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with abhi and this is exactly how Playorm has implemented it. You may see the code of columnSlice() API at https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alvazan/orm/layer9z/spi/db/cassandra/CassandraSession.java

Also, if you are using Playorm for Cassandra you can just use its ColumnSlice API. The example is given at https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/alvazan/test/TestColumnSlice.java

Comment: Could you please refer to the following link also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744575/querying-columns-with-prefix-not-working-using-astyanax

I am working on a problem described there.
Thanks im advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could just use PlayOrm Query language as well if you final goal is getting the entities out.